# Texts of different sizes in 4 divs

Tags: html, css

I have texts with different sizes and I want to put them into 4 divs in the middle of the page like that
[image http://firepic.org/images/2015-08/22/0b0r536o40es.png](http://firepic.org/images/2015-08/22/0b0r536o40es.png)

but it seems what my pink `div` pushes the bottom ones down.
How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide your code.

Comment: Use a table for the text with 2 rows and 2 columns if you want the same height and width of the boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.wrapper {
  background: grey;
  height: 280px;
  width: 280px;
}
p {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#one {
  background: blue;
  float: left;
  width: 140px;
  height:140px;
  text-align: center;
  
}
#two {
  background: pink;
  float: right;
  width: 140px;
  height:200px;
  text-align: center;
}
#three {
  background: aqua;
  float: left;
  width: 140px;
  height:140px;
  text-align: center;
}
#four {
   background: green;
  float: right;
  width: 140px;
  height:80px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="one"><p>TEXT</p></div>
<div id="two"><p>TEXT</p></div>
<div id="three"><p>TEXT</p></div>
<div id="four"><p>TEXT</p></div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired functionality the following way using a table

```css
table {
  width: 50%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: auto;
}
tr > td {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="background: lightblue;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium, officiis facere dignissimos saepe voluptates, porro itaque eveniet reiciendis eius perferendis?</td>
    <td style="background: pink">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores asperiores inventore eveniet quas praesentium, dignissimos cum omnis architecto</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background: royalblue;">Lorem ipsum dolor inventore libero qui explicabo ea incidunt maxime blanditiis assumenda? Iusto, at ipsam eveniet!</td>
    <td style="background: cyan;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium quis, quo ea est nostrum veniam?</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```